# LNK 2001: Unresolve external symbol struct **

Tags: c, struct, key-value, key-value-coding

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <ctype.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

//typedef struct kvNode kvNode;

struct kvNode
{
    char cKey[32];
    uint32_t iValue;
    struct kvNode *NEXT;
};

//Function declarations
void put(char *key[], int *value);
uint32_t get(char *key[]);
int del(char *key[]);
uint32_t hashkey(char *key);
void strUpper(char *);

const int arraylen = 10; //length of key array
kvNode *keys[]; //our key array

int main()
{
    //Create array of pointers to kvNodes
    keys[arraylen] = { NULL };
    return 0;
}
```

I'm pretty sure this is the block of code returning the error. The error happens during build time and is:

> 1>keyValue.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "struct kvNode * * keys" (?keys@@3PAPAUkvNode@@A)

What I'm trying to do is practice a key value store in C (undoubtedly using more, shall we say, *relaxed* languages recently has dulled my C knife), so I define a key value node struct, then an array of pointers to those nodes. Following other questions on SO about forward declaring of structs I got the syntax for declaring a pointer to the struct inside the struct, but for some reason the compiler (Vis Studio) is coughing on an unresolved external symbol and I don't know why.

Comment: Is this line: `kvNode *keys[]; //our key array` as is when you compiled the program? You have commented above the line with the typedef so this line should be `struct kvNode *keys[]; //our key array`, but then your linker issues an error about `struct kvNode **keys` which doesn't exist in your source code. So, is this the actual code that produced the error?

Comment: Yeah Chris got it spot on, the compiler needs to know the size of the array, which makes sense, but I'll have to go in a different direction for my program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare a size for this array `kvNode *keys[]; //our key array`

If the size is not known at compile time, how can the compiler compile it? It's being declared to have static lifetime, so it has to be given a fixed size, a fixed block of memory in your binary. I think the compiler is interpreting the above line as a declaration and not a definition, hence the link error.

Comment: Makes sense, perhaps I need to ask a separate question but what if the size won't be known until the program is run?

Comment: Well, in that case, you should allocate it on the heap using malloc, or if your compiler supports variable length arrays, you could allocate it on the stack (as a local variable in a function). You didn't say what standard of C you are working with.

Comment: Yeah that did the trick, can accept in 9 mins apparently. I'll have to see what standard Vis Studio compiles in by default, but that points me in the right direction, thanks.

Comment: @BigHomie Then you can't make it a global array. Typically you'd allocate the array at runtime (with `malloc`) and have a global pointer to the first element of it.

Comment: @immibis sounds like the way I'll go.

Answer (score 0):

this is a compile time problem, not a link time problem. with this line:

```
kvNode *keys[];
```

which has a couple of problems.

First, the syntax is not correct:.  it should be:

```
struct kvNode *keys[];
```

But that does not handle this next line because the compiler will default to only a single item sized keys[]

```
keys[arraylen] = { NULL };
```

suggest:

```
struct kvNode *keys[ arraylen ];
```

even then, this line:

```
keys[arraylen] = { NULL };
```

is trying to set keys[10] which will be past the end of the array of pointers.  Because in C, array indexing starts with 0 not 1 so the valid indexes for keys[] are 0...9

Strongly suggest always enable all warnings when compiling, then fix those warnings.

Strongly suggest performing the compile step separately from the link step so you can easily determine which step actually contains the root of a problem